# Clang splits function arguments

Tags: c, clang, llvm

If you compile the following with "clang -S -emit-llvm struct.c"

```
struct _mystruct {
  long long int a;
  long long int b;
};

struct _mystruct foo(struct _mystruct s) {
  s.a += 1;
  return s;
}

int main(void) {
  struct _mystruct s;
  s.a = 8;
  s.b = 9;
  s = foo(s);
  return s.a;
}
```

... you get (among other things):

```
define { i64, i64 } @foo(i64 %s.coerce0, i64 %s.coerce1) #0 {
```

Why does clang split the argument to foo in two?  Is there any way I can prevent it from doing that?  I want to be able to call it from other LLVM generated code that expects only one argument to foo.

Comment: Are you sure that LLVM will not generate the correct calling code? I suspect it will do the right thing. Pass foo a struct in your C code, llvm will change to two longs. Am I missing something?

Comment: The code calling into it will be generated using LLVM, but not clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LLVM has no way to represent it, Clang encodes the platform ABI this way. In this particular example, it's struct passing by-value which is extremely ABI specific. You will notice this if you provide different target triple to clang - you'll notice that the emitted code is different. I assume from the question this is run on a x64 machine where structs can be passed in registers.